# How do I configure JetBrains IDEs so that autocomplete of a HTML element places the cursor inside the element?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Currently, when I'm starting to write `<div class="row` and then press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Enter</kbd> for autocompletion, my cursor lands at the end of the closed `div`, like this

```
<div class="row"></div>█
```

How can I configure the IDE (specifically WebStorm and PyCharm, but I guess the config is all the same), to place the cursor inside the `div` like this

```
<div class="row">█</div>
```

?

Or even better, autoformat it on autocompletion so that this is the result:

```
<div class="row">
█
</div>
```

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` is for "Complete Current Statement" action. It meant to work this way -- to place the caret at the end of the block/statement. Try Emmet instead -- just type `.row` and press the expend key (which should be `Tab`  by default; if not -- check in settings). Or you can just finish typing your `<div class="row` to close the opening element (just 2 more symbols accordingly to your example: `">` and you will get the desired result.

Comment: Didn't know about Emmet, thanks for that!